# Django: use a chain or a new order number field for sorting a large set of items?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a set of items that are due for people in a system and some items are in a checklist and others are just used for display. I want to get a list of items for display, and a list of items in order for a checklist report showing items still not completed. I was hoping to get some insight on performance and options for ordering items. I could a) add a field "order" as a positive integer and order them by that order number, or b) create a chain object where one item has a next link to the next item in the chain so I can iterate through rapidly.

I guess the second option would require more overhead from the database since it would require a SQL call each time calling item.next, right? The benefit of making a chain would be in resorting the items when I need to make an ordering change.

Any thoughts on performance, and maintainability for which direction I should go? This is a general case question, would it generally be better to use SQL to get the ordering or create a data structure like a chain to iterate?

Comment: Depends on the requirement. I would go with the SQL. ORDER BY date or field id or the field value it self.

Comment: I think it's better to use the "order" field. Because you'll show items more often than change them. And change of order will require just several queries.

Comment: How exactly do you benefit from chained structure kept in SQL table?

Comment: @Krzysiek, when I want to add a new element at position x, I simply need to change `item[x-1].next=new_item` and `new_item.next=item[x]`, instead of updating the order for all elements after position x. @sneawo, you are right, I don't need to change the order very often, but will use the order often and can get it in a single query. Thanks for the input, guys.

Comment: I think one update query on reorder is nice trade off for avoiding n (possibly thousend) queries to get n-th element.

Imagine pagination done that way.